# Edit a specific part of a txt file and save the changes

Tags: python, txt

I'm trying to display information from a txt file and then save whatever changes were made and write it back to the txt file.

```
            with open("tasks.txt", 'r') as t_file:
                for line in t_file:
                    if line.startswith(username):
                        users_tasks_list.append(line)
                        for count, ele in enumerate(users_tasks_list, 1):
                            if task_select == int(count):
                                task_info = ele.split(",")
                                # I want to display the information in this format
                                print("\n" + " Task:\t\t" + task_info[1]
                                      + "\n" + "Assigned to:\t\t " + task_info[0]
                                      + "\n" + "Date assigned:\t" + task_info[3]
                                      + "\n" + "Due date:\t\t" + task_info[4]
                                      + "\n" + "Task complete?\t" + task_info[5]
                                      + "\n" + "Description:"
                                      + "\n" + task_info[2])

                                while True:
                                    # If the task is not completed entering 1 must change No to Yes
                                    # Entering 2 should allow you to edit the user of the task or the due date
                                    task_edit = int(input("\nEnter 1 to mark the task as complete \nEnter 2 to edit the task \nEnter 0 to return \n"))
                                    if task_edit == 1:
                                        task_info[5] = "Yes"
                                        t_file = open("tasks.txt", "w")
                                        user_tasks = " ".join(users_tasks_list)
                                        t_file.write(user_tasks)
                                        t_file.close()
                                        print("Task completed")
                                        

                                    elif task_edit == 2:
                                        print("success")
                                        if task_info[5] == "No":
                                            task_change = int(input("\nEnter 1 to edit the User \nEnter 2 to edit the due date of the task \n"))
```

This is what I have, I'm struggling to save the information back to the txt file.

The information on the txt file is in the format below:

assigned to (e.g. user), task title, task description, date assigned (in the format: dd mmm yyyy), due date (in the format: dd mmm yyyy), task complete (e.g. No)

Each task should be on a new line.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One way to solve this is to read the entire file, make the change, then write all the data back to the file. Alternatively, you can use a so-called "random access" file.

Comment: Could you explain to me how I could go about doing this?

Comment: Each task should be on a new line so if I need to edit the second task of a specific user. I looked up random access and it said that it does not work on a text file.

Comment: Right. For random access, you will have to use a binary format. If that's not possible, you can use my first suggestion.